# gnuplot: y-axis values in math-mode give extra offset from y-label compared to no-math mode in cairo-latex terminal

Tags: math-mode, gnuplot

I'm using the 'cairo-latex' terminal.

The y-axis values are 10^1, 10^2 and 10^3 in logscale.

When I set this values output in math-mode as '10$^1$', or '$10^1$',
the figure ratio is changed --- the y axis is shifted in right direction (so the x-axis gets more narrow), and I have the empty space between the y-label and the y-axis values.

When I output values in text-mode like '10^1', everything is ok.

Why the math mode reserves extra space for value, and how to change it?

Have anybody sent a bugreport to the gnuplot team?
Or this is a feature of gnuplot, which they will not change?

Thanks.